# Spring Aspect + WebFlux. What behavior is expected?

Tags: spring-aop, spring-webflux

Im trying to create my `@Around` annotation to make `Prometheus` metrics.

**Aspect:**

```
@Around("@annotation(TimeMetric)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        // duration.startTimer(); 
        Object object = joinPoint.proceed();
        // durationTimer.setDuration();

        return object;
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
@TimeMetric
@GetMapping(path = "")
Mono<SomeResult> health() {
    return Mono.just(service.doSomeJob());
}
```

My expected behaviour is:

> I will get metrics without execution time `service.doSomeJob()`, as I 
>   return `Mono`.

But when I am getting result I see:

> that result metrics includes expected time `service.doSomeJob()`

Does `Aspect` block my method or what the trick? Im trying to find there some performance omission?

Comment: How about an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) enabling others to reproduce your problem? You do not even explain what the aspect is supposed to do. Is this commented-out `durationTimer` active in your real code? If so, then you are setting a duration by yourself with the `setDuration()` call. So why are you surprised that a duration is registered in the metrics? BTW, your aspect is not blocking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this method is just wrapping a synchronous value:

```
Mono.just(service.doSomeJob());
```

So `service.doSomeJob()` is called synchronously (I hope it's not doing blocking I/O...) and the time spent in it is directly spent while building the reactive pipeline.